# String.split(String regex) unexpected behaviour?

Tags: java, string

`String.split(String delim);` is behaving strangely, It is returning spliting the string at every character and returning an output exactly like `String.toCharArray();` [and it is driving me nuts]

Here is how you can reproduce my problem:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("CENTURY:a,b,c|HALF_CENTURY:c,d,e".split("|")));
```

Output: [, C, E, N, T, U, R, Y, :, a, ,, b, ,, c, |, H, A, L, F, _, C, E, N, T, U, R, Y, :, c, ,, d, ,, e]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.split(regex)` accepts **regex**. In regex world `|` is a `meta character(special character)`, escape it with `\\` in order to treat it as a `normal character`.

```
Arrays.toString("CENTURY:a,b,c|HALF_CENTURY:c,d,e".split("\\|"));
```

or embed it inside `character class`, `[|]`

```
Arrays.toString("CENTURY:a,b,c|HALF_CENTURY:c,d,e".split("[|]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"CENTURY:a,b,c|HALF_CENTURY:c,d,e".split("|");
```

That doesn't work because the argument to split is actually a regular expression, where | has a special meaning.

The reason is that the argument to split() is compiled into a regular expression; and characters which are special in regex need to be quoted

the backslash is also the escape characters for strings in general, and needs to be doubled

Try this:

```
"CENTURY:a,b,c|HALF_CENTURY:c,d,e".split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
split("\\|")
```

you need to escape the `|`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `Pattern.quote(String)`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) for details.